# Azure AD B2C - audit logs not reflecting user authentications

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm doing a trial of Azure AD B2C to potentially handle all our B2C identities.

I've been following this sample:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi

I have the signup, signin, password change and sign out processes working with our application, however I've been looking at these logs and can can't see any of my consumer user authentications:

- Azure Active Directory - Audit logs
- Azure Active Directory - Sign-ins

I can see a number of events, including authentications, relating to the user that is my directory *administrator*, but not the indivudual users.

I've found this FAQ:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

It states that

> - The sign-in reports provide a record of each sign-in with reduced details.
> - Audit reports are available in the Azure portal, under Azure Active Directory> ACTIVITY-Audit logs>Choose B2C and apply filters as
>     desired. Both admin activity as well as application activity are
>     covered.

I'm using the AD free tier at the moment and there is a hint that user sign-ins might not be logged unless using AD Premium. When I open the overview of one of the consumer users, under Summary - Users Sign-ins it says "Start a free trial to use this feature."

Do I need to use AD Premium to see B2C sign-in log entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User authentications are currently not available in audit logs for Azure AD B2C. It is in the plans though. You may want to still put the idea in the feedback forum so others can vote for it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Comment: Done! https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31709326-log-user-authentications-in-azure-active-directory